# Sed replace line start with space & # character beside varriable substituation

Tags: sed

i have a little problem in sed, i want to replace the following line :

```
space here#Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/varr1/var2/*.conf"
```

or

```
space here# Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/varr1/varr2/*.conf"
```

(note the space after #)

to the following

```
Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/varr1/varr2/*.conf"
```

the following code works, with line that doesn't start with space :

```
sed -i "s/# Include \"\/usr\/local\/apache\/conf\/userdata\/std\/2\/$varr1\/$varr2\/\*.conf\"/Include \"\/usr\/local\/apache\/conf\/userdata\/std\/2\/$varr1\/$varr2\/\*.conf\"/" file.name
```

any help will be appreciated,
thank all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write the path, just capture it:

```
sed -i 's!# *Include \("[^"]*"\)!Include \1!' input.file
```

Comment: ? OP can have many different _Includes_, and he said he want to replace only 2 paths.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `/` as delimiter, you can pick up any character you want instead.

By example :

```
sed -i 's@@@g' file
```

So, no need to put backslashes on everything, this is difficult to read for humans beings.

Finally, try doing this :

```
 sed -i 's@^ *# *Include \+"/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/varr1/var\+2/\*\.conf"@Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/varr1/varr2/*.conf"@g' file.name
```

**NOTE**

- `*` character mean *zero or N occurrences* in regex
- `^` character mean *start of line*
- `*` & `.` are special characters, so they are backslashed. Later means *any single character*

Comment: sputnick, thank you so much, sorry this doesnt work, but i really appretiate your kind try